# Playground in Xcode 8 error terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

it is my first time using Playgrounds in Xcode
but when I create a new playground, I didn't write any line of code but it stuck in Running then show me this error

```
> 2016-09-30 17:52:45.591 MyPlaygroundgggg[1946:22425] *** NSForwarding: warning: selector (0x11908fc82) for message
> 'processInfo' does not match selector known to Objective C runtime
> (0x10cd894d5)-- abort 2016-09-30 17:52:45.797
> MyPlaygroundgggg[1946:22425] +[NSProcessInfo processInfo]:
> unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a1c26f8 2016-09-30
> 17:52:46.606 MyPlaygroundgggg[1946:22425] *** Terminating app due to
> uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> '+[NSProcessInfo processInfo]: unrecognized selector sent to class
> 0x10a1c26f8'
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a8ff34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib   
> 0x000000010a36021e objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation      
> 0x000000010a96ee74 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
> 132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a884c15
> ___forwarding___ + 1013   4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a884798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   PlaygroundLogger  
> 0x000000011908a5c7
> _TTSf4gs_g_d___TZFC16PlaygroundLogger11Environment3getfT8variableSS12defaultValueGSqSS__GSqSS_
> + 103     6   PlaygroundLogger                    0x000000011907929b _TTSf4d___TFCO16PlaygroundLogger9Woodchuck12InstanceDataCfT_S1_ + 107    7   PlaygroundLogger                    0x0000000119071629
> globalinit_33_9A595A25FCBAC90B0D0056FBEBBB0699_func5 + 9  8  
> libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dd9712e
> _dispatch_client_callout + 8  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dd81e12 dispatch_once_f + 68     10  PlaygroundLogger         
> 0x000000011908c331 playground_logger_initialize + 113     11  ???        
> 0x0000000119364069 0x0 + 4717953129   12  MyPlaygroundgggg             
> 0x0000000109d89620 main + 0   13  CoreFoundation                     
> 0x000000010a8a425c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12   14 
> CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a889304
> __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356     15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a888a75 __CFRunLoopRun + 901     16  CoreFoundation           
> 0x000000010a888494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     17  GraphicsServices   
> 0x000000010fc93a6f GSEventRunModal + 161  18  UIKit                   
> 0x000000010b432f34 UIApplicationMain + 159    19  MyPlaygroundgggg      
> 0x0000000109d896e9 main + 201     20  libdyld.dylib                      
> 0x000000010dde068d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
> uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is a snapshot of the playground file:

[Snapshot of the Playground file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8n6S.png)

I tried to restart both Xcode and my computer but same error
I am using macOS Sierra 10.12 
MacBook pro 15-inch, Early 2011
Ram 4 GB

Comment: Try creating a new playground with a different name.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I already did but same error

Comment: Re executing the playground worked for me

Comment: I also have a similar error with a different playground. Re-executing the playground sometimes resolves the problem but it is inconsistent and annoying